# How do I know the actual type and size of the return type of a non-static method in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, sizeof, decltype, non-static

In C++, we can use `sizeof` and `decltype` on non-static data member of a function, but either of them doesn't work on non-static method's return type, e.g. `decltype(std::vector<int>::size())`, `sizeof(std::vector<int>::size())`, any reason why this is restricted? or there are some way works i didn't discovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifier needs to be given a legal expression - something you could use in actual code. So you can create an instance and call the member on that instance like this:

```
decltype(std::vector<int>().size())
```

It is the same for the [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator. It needs to receive a legal expression.

Comment: But any reason why the non-static data member is allowed, `std::pair<int, int>::first` is not a legal expression?

Comment: @AlanJian That works because it is an _entity_ (or an expression yielding an entity). According to the reference linked, that is a different case, it is a `class member access` expression, in which case it yeilds its type. *Quote:* _"If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields the type of the entity named by this expression."_ See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: So if the expression yields an *entity* you can use the `decltype` to yield the type of that entity. But if the expression yields a value - it needs to be a valid expression that really would yield that value in code. Then `decltype` can return the type of that value.